# Creating a Surface of Revolution

Tags: python, matplotlib, 3d, surface

I have a 3d plot of a disk, here is the code:

```
ri = 100
ra = 300
h=20

# input xy coordinates
xy = np.array([[ri,0],[ra,0],[ra,h],[ri,h],[ri,0]])
# radial component is x values of input
r = xy[:,0]
# angular component is one revolution of 30 steps
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 50)
# create grid
R,Phi = np.meshgrid(r,phi)
# transform to cartesian coordinates
X = R*np.cos(Phi)
Y = R*np.sin(Phi)
# Z values are y values, repeated 30 times
Z = np.tile(xy[:,1],len(Y)).reshape(Y.shape)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection='3d')

ax.set_zlim(0,200)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, alpha=0.5, color='grey', rstride=1, cstride=1)
```

I get this nice plot:
[image]

Further I have this plot:
[image]

The code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

arr = np.array([[100, 15],
               [114.28, 17],
               [128.57, 18],
               [142.85, 19],
               [157.13, 22],
               [171.13, 24],
               [185.69, 25],
               [199.97, 27],
               [214.25, 28],
               [228.53, 30],
               [242.81, 31],
               [257.09, 35],
               [271.37, 36],
               [288.65, 37],
               [300, 38]])

#interpolating between the single values of the arrays
new_x = np.concatenate([np.linspace(arr[i,0],arr[i+1,0], num=50)
                        for i in range(len(arr)-1)])

new_y = np.interp(new_x, arr[:,0], arr[:,1])
t=np.arange(700)
p = plt.scatter(new_x,new_y,c=t, cmap="jet")

#inserting colorbar
cax, _ = mpl.colorbar.make_axes(plt.gca(), shrink=0.8)
cbar = mpl.colorbar.ColorbarBase(cax, cmap='jet', label='testvalues',
                       norm=mpl.colors.Normalize(15, 40))
plt.show()
```

Now my question: 
Is there a way to plot this 2d graph into my 3d environment? Further is it possible to create a surface out of this line (points) by rotating them around the middlepoint ? I tried it the same way like I did it with my disk but I failed because I think I need a closed contour ? Here is a picture to understand better what I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure how you want to include your 2d plot, so here's how you do it as a surface of revolution.

Your `new_x` corresponds to radial distance, `new_y` corresponds to height. So we need to generate an array of angles for which to generate the "cone":

```
from matplotlib import cm

tmp_phi = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,50)[:,None] # angle data
linesurf_x = new_x*np.cos(tmp_phi)
linesurf_y = new_x*np.sin(tmp_phi)
linesurf_z = np.broadcast_to(new_y, linesurf_x.shape)

linesurf_c = np.broadcast_to(t, linesurf_x.shape) # color according to t
colors = cm.jet(linesurf_c/linesurf_c.max()) # grab actual colors for the surface
ax.plot_surface(linesurf_x, linesurf_y, linesurf_z, facecolors=colors,
                rstride=1, cstride=1)
```

Result:

[image: picture]

Comment: @albo22 I'm glad I could help. Tangential to your problem here, but consider using a perceptually uniform colormap such as `viridis`. For a detailed explanation of the problem, [see here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xAoljeRJ3lU) :)

Comment: I can't get it to work, I get the error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'sqrt' Do you have any idea what's the issue?

Comment: @albo22 there's no sqrt in the above, even if I think about underlying methods. Do you have `sqrt` in your (not shown) code?

Comment: Actually I don't have any sqrt in my code. I just copied the second code (with my colored line) into my first code (3d disk plot) and at the end I added your code. I think there went some wrong with an import because before the error message there are couple of messages which looks like this: 
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 902, in set_sizes
    scale = np.sqrt(self._sizes) * dpi / 72.0 * self._factor

Comment: @albo22 indeed, if that error comes there that would mean that `np is None`. Which would be hilariously odd. Unfortunately I don't see where this problem could come from if you just put my code block after your first one, with the appropriate imports...

Comment: Okay, i got it to work now, it was a simple typo... Unfortunately, it's not exactly what I imagined. Is there a way to highlight the contour of the function a bit better, because in 2d graphs you see more corners? I suppose it would be more visible if you scale the whole contour a bit, because it's a little flattened? Is there a possibility to increase the performance without a big loss of quality, because it is already quite laggy when turning and creating the plot. Is it also possible to remove the black lines (which can also be seen on your plot)?

Comment: @albo22 I tried hiding the lines by setting `edgecolor='none'` which didn't help. Perhaps `linewidth=0` can help but I'm not sure. There may also be a chance that exporting the figure to pdf will look different, I'm not sure. For performance: you can reduce the number of points used in the mesh: now there are 50 angular points (not that many) and 700 radial points (many). Setting the appropriate `rstride`/`cstride` to a larger number should reduce the latter, find a value that looks similar but has fewer facets. As for the scale: you can multiply `linesurf_z` to make the cone higher.

Comment: thanks to your tips, I've done it now relatively well looking. I still need a colorbar. If I add the colorbar as I did before, then now comes an error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'make_axes'. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @albo22 you're probably using `plt.colorbar` rather than `mpl.colorbar`. I have no experience with adding colorbars like that, though.